# Atlases such that all finite intersections are contractible

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds

This question was asked in assignments in my online course on Manifolds and I was not able to solve this.

> Question: Consider $S^1 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ as a submanifold. Find an atlas $ \psi: O_i \subset \mathbb{R}\to S^1$, $U_i = \psi_i(O_i)$ such that all finite intersections $U_{i_1 } \cap ... \cap U_{i_k}$ are contractible , if not empty. Find an atlas for 2-torus as well.

Attempt: If $U_{i_1} \cap ...\cap U_{i_k}$ are empty then there is nothing to find. So, let them be non-empty: Now, a topological space is called contractible if the identity map on X is null homotopic ie it is homotopic to some constant map.

Now, using the definition of homotopy, there exists a  map $H:  \mathbb{R} \times [0,1] \to S^1$.

$H(x,0)= x $ and $H(x,1) =c$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

I have been given this map in the question. I have to find such an atlas.

But I am not able to move forward from this!

Kindly help me.

Comment: For the circle, draw a picture: three arcs are sufficient. For the torus, also draw a picture, this would give you and idea for the answer

Comment: Who is $X$ in your "there exists a  map $H:  \mathbb{R} \times [0,1] \to S^1$. $H(x,0)= x $ [...] for $x\in X$." ?

Comment: Once you have handled the circle $S^1$, you can use that the torus is $S^1\times S^1.$

Comment: For the circle, three may be sufficient, but four may be easier to describe and treat.

Comment: @AnneBauval I think it is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Can you please elaborate by writing an answer? It will really help me. This hint is not sufficient for me.

Comment: Then edit your post to replace $X$ by $\Bbb R.$

Comment: This is totally confused. The $X$ in question is one of those intersections of members of the atlas. Any proper open interval in $S^1$ is contractible.

Comment: This is an *existence* problem: Does there *exist* an atlas with these properties? A correct answer would include a concrete description of an appropriate atlas $\{\psi_i : O_i \to S^1\}_{i \in I}$ followed by a proof that the atlas described satisfies the properties.

Comment: Using your skills in analytic geometry (i.e. coordinate geometry in the plane), you could look at the picture in the answer of @JohnPalmieri and write down such an atlas explicitly.

Comment: @3ibfwcbi It has been a month that an answer is posted, without any reply. Several comments have been made to give hints to write an explicit proof without any reaction. May we now why you don't reply to these but put a bounty instead? (this is an actual question, not a passive-aggressive mean remark)

Comment: @Didier I would prefer if you write a proof instead of a hints in this particular question. I am having a really hard time following the hints. I am not able to follow hints for this question. I had to take a 2nd course on manifolds without doing a 1st course.

Comment: @3ibfwcbi Then read carefully the last hint of Lee Mosher: you surely knows how to parametrize the circle and how to determine which angles coaresly corresponds to the coloured region of the circle in the posted answer right? Another hint: forget about homotopies! You just need to know that intervals are contractible. For instance, the intersection of the red and the blue region (hopefully you're not colourblind) looks very similar to an interval right?

Comment: See the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Didier said in the comments:

[image]

Edit: to define the atlas, first choose the arcs. Let's define them by their angles: a first guess is that they could be $(0, 2\pi/3)$, $(2\pi/3, 4\pi/3)$, and $(4\pi/3, 2\pi)$, but those don't overlap, so expand them a bit, so for example let $\theta=\pi/5$ and use $(0, 2\pi/3 + \theta)$, $(2\pi/3, 4\pi/3 + \theta)$, and $(4\pi/3, 2\pi + \theta)$.

Now find a map from an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ to each arc. That's just basic analytic geometry: if the arc ranges in angle from $\alpha$ to $\beta$ with $\alpha < \beta$, define $\phi: (\alpha,\beta) \to S^1$ by $\phi(t) = (\sin(t), \cos(t))$.

Having done that, the image of each $\phi$ is homeomorphic to an open interval, the intersection of any two is also homeomorphic to an open interval, and the intersection of all three is empty. So it remains to show that open intervals are contractible. (This relies on the basic observation that contractibility is a topological invariant: if $X$ is contractible and $X$ is homeomorphic to $Y$, then $Y$ is contractible.) Of course every open interval is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, so let's just show that $\mathbb{R}$ is contractible.

Define $H: \mathbb{R} \times [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ by $H(s,t) = s (1-t)$. Then $H(s,0) = s$ and $H(s,1)=0$ for all $s$, so $H$ defines a homotopy from the identity map on $\mathbb{R}$ to the constant map at 0.

Comment: For completeness: call this atlas $\{(U_i,\phi_i)\}_{i=1,2,3}$. Then $\{(U_i\times U_j,\phi_i\times\phi_j)\}_{i,j=1,2,3}$ will be an atlas of $S^1\times S^1$ satisfying the required property.

Comment: @Didier: yes, thank you.