# How to prove that $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism

Tags: manifolds, diffeomorphism

This question was asked in my assignment on Manifolds and I was not able to prove it.

> Question: Prove that if $\phi: M \to N$ is $C^{\infty}$, 1-1 , onto and everywhere non-singular then $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism.

Attempt: Definition of diffeomorphism is as follows: If $\phi$ is a $C^{\infty}$ map from M to N then if $\phi$ is 1-1 , onto and $\phi^{-1}$ is $C^{\infty}$ then $\phi$ is called a diffeomorphism.

$\phi$ is everywhere non-singular implies that kernel of  $d \phi$ is {0}. But I am not able think on how to relate non singularity with the $C^{\infty}$ condition and hence I am not able to make any significant progress.

Kindly give some hints!

Comment: Do you happen to know the inverse function theorem and the constant rank theorem?

Comment: @Didier Yes. I will try to apply those. Thanks!

Comment: Then apply them in the reverse order: first, constant rank theorem (to show both manifolds have the same dimension), and then, the inverse function theorem (to show the inverse is smooth)

Comment: @Didier Can you please have a look at this also?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4555137/atlases-such-that-all-finite-intersections-are-contractible

Comment: This is really ironic. I already gave a big hint on this question a month ago, and have asked you something in the comments section no later than yesterday / today (depending on your time zone). It would be polite to have a look at this question yourself before asking me to do so!